# How to post list of interface objects into ASP.NET WebApi Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to post a model containing a list of interface objects into an WebApi controller action?

When I do it as follows my model is not null but the property "Items" contains no entries.

Here is my code:

**Controller.js**

```
public void Post(MyModel model)
{
   ...
}
```

**MyModel.cs**

```
public class MyModel
{      
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**IItem.cs**

```
public interface IItem
{
    string Test1 { get; set; }
    string Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Item.cs**

```
public class Item : IItem
{
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

I think it is possible with a custom model binder, but I don't find a suitable example.

Comment: Controller action requires parameterless constructor of custom model class, but interface doesn't have it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware the default model binder can only bind concrete classes, so changing the MyModel.Items property to:

```
IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

should work as expected. However if you can't change the type for some reason you can either:

1. Create a custom model binder to support the IItem interface as you've  already mentioned
2. Create a view model using only concrete classes. You will need to map your existing type to the view model however this is much easier than writing a custom model binder IMO.